# How to make a button which can toggle darkmode?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const sec = document.querySelector('.sec');
    const toggle = document.querySelector('.sec');
toggle.onclick = function() {
    sec.classList.toggle('dark')
}
```

```css
section
{
  position: relative;
  background: #fcfcfc;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around; I tried to fill the whole website with: space around
  align-items: center;
  
}
section.dark
{
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); 

}
.toggle{ 
  position: absolute;
top: 1%;
right: -75%;
background: #ffffff;
width: 5%;
height: 5%;
border-radius: 50%;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
align-items: center; 
cursor: pointer;
margin-top: 1%;
}
.toggle:before{
  content: '☼';
  font-family: fontAwesome; 
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 1%;
}
section.dark .toggle::before{
  content: '☽';
}
```

```html
<section class="sec"> section
<div class="toggle"></div> toggle button
<div class="container" id="container">
```

**I know this is allready a darkmode but if I click on the screen the darkmode activites also. And not the whole website gets dark :/**

Comment: You wish to click a button to toggle the entire website appearance from light to dark and back again? Rather than toggle a single style set different stylesheets

Comment: There is no button in your HTML, only a div element. Think about using a real `<button type="button">` element for semantics.

Comment: Please give it a read https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_dark_mode.asp
This will help you in building the dark mode

Comment: Could you put this into a jsfiddle so it would be easier for people to experiment with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beacause you have given wrong classname for toggle button in javascript code thats why on screen click it activates. It should be
`const toggle = document.querySelector('.toggle');`

Comment: @Theprofessor Also rather than toggling the class for the current `<section>` you should toggle the `dark` class in the body (and change your CSS accordingly), so the whole page can be affected by CSS and not just article sections.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS variables along with the data-theme attribute of the html tag to achieve this.
Here is what you should do with your html:

```html
<html lang="en" data-theme="light">
```

This sets the default theme to light. In your CSS, you can have selectors for the html tag of a specific attribute like so `html[data-theme="light"]` and `html[data-theme="dark"]`.
You will have to declare different values for the same variables in each of these tags. These variables will allow you to style your whole page based on the current theme.
You can read more about css variables here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

```css
/* Themes */
html[data-theme="light"] {
  --clr-bg: rgba();
  --clr-container: rgba();
  --clr-text: rgba();
}
html[data-theme="dark"] {
  --clr-bg: rgba();
  --clr-container: rgba();
  --clr-text: rgba();
}
/* You will have to fill in the rgba values */
```

You will only need to add the JS to switch between dark and light values of the html data-theme attribute. You can easily achieve this with `document.querySelector('html').setAttribute("data-theme", "dark")` and `document.querySelector('html').setAttribute("data-theme", "light")`.
I have a github repository on this, it might be helpful.
https://github.com/samyukt-g/DarkModeToggle